# SQLServer Remote Management - Is SF the right place to ask?

Tags: discussion

I have a question on suspected deviation from the MS documentation regarding SQL Server 2016 installed on Server-Core and how its managed, specifically why certain features don't seem to be available from the remote management (GUI) side? It could also be an install foul-up although I couldn't immediately see why.

The problem the question is trying to address can almost certainly be solved another way, via powershell, but I'd like to know if there is a reason, or my lack of knowledge that is why remote management appears deficient.

This is for a test, rather than production setup, although the issue presumably would apply to either - does this run foul of the 'no development environment questions'?

Comment: Will you eventually deploy it to production, or are you doing _programming_?

Comment: Its a trial of Always-On as much as anything, this iteration won't be going into production.

Answer (score 4):

My personal opinion is that if its some trouble to manage a sql 2016 on a server core, I see an use for the question, as often an admin will use the management studio, to create backup and such.